# django format date on user supplied locale

Tags: django, localization, django-templates, django-i18n, django-localflavor

I'm trying to set up the formatting of dates in templates based on a locale supplied by the user.  As the rest of the page will remain in the original local ('en'), I only want my users'
 supplied data to be formatted.

for example, dates.

users in the uk should be able to use `l10n` on the dates on their pages, but I don't want to set the whole site to be `en_GB`.

is there a way to set the locale in a template within a block, eg. something like

```
{% locale|'en_GB' %}
    {{ my_date|localize }}
{% endlocale %}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do anything explicit in the template.

Inside your `settings.py` define the `FORMAT_MODULE_PATH` setting.
Like:

```
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = 'myproject.myapp.formats'
```

under the `formats` directory create one python package *per* supported language(other
than your default) of your project. Inside each of these you should have a `formats.py`
which should have any localized formatting options.

In my case the default language for my project is `en`, but I also support `el`(greek).
So I have this in my `settings.py`:

```
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = 'myproject.websiteapp.formats'
```

Inside the `myproject/websiteapp/formats` directory I have a `el` package with a `formats.py` file, like:

```
el/
 __init__.py
 formats.py
```

Inside the `formats.py` I have this:

```
DATETIME_FORMAT="l j M Y, g:i a"
```

which is the greek specific representation of a date.

So when I use a datetime field inside my templates:

```
{{ mymodel.pub_date }}
```

It prints the default `en` representation when locale is set to the default:

```
Published on: Feb. 22, 2013, 1:47 p.m.
```

and my custom greek one when the locale is set to `el`.

```
Δημοσιεύτηκε: Τετάρτη 6 Φεβ 2013, 5:39 μμ.
```

More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#format-module-path)

**Edit**

Hmm, I just realized that you asked for specific template blocks or values.
Maybe the [localize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/formatting/#std%3atemplatefilter-localize) template *filter* or the [localize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/formatting/#std%3atemplatetag-localize) template *tag*
are more relevant to your specific case?